# Why does JavaFX add extra spacing between letters when using the Text component and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, text, java-8, javafx-8

I'm trying to use the text component of JavaFX to do some nice headline typography in my application. How ever the letters in the text are not spaced evenly. For example in the word "*visiting*", the "*iting*" part seems disconnected from the first part.

[image: sample text image]

In the sample image I'm using Arial but this kind of bad spacing happens with every font I tried.

This only happens when "gray" anti-aliasing is used (`-fx-font-smoothing-type: gray;`). One obvious solution would be to change `-fx-font-smoothing-type` to lcd, but that would result in the text having jagged edges.

The only thing remotely mentioning something like this is the jira issue [RT-14187](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-14187), but that seem to have been resolved in javafx 8 (jre 8).

Comment: Interestingly, Stack Overflow questions are rendered in Arial (in my browser, at least), and the word "*visiting*" in your question clearly shows the same issue.

Comment: It would since it's an image.

Comment: You also have that word in your question’s text, which is what I was referring to.

Comment: Are you using Linux? If so, this could be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49161467/261769